# How to store oauth_token_secret in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, twitter-oauth

I can store the oauth_token in mysql database but how to store oauth_token_secret ? I guess, I need both oauth_token as well as oauth_token_secret to tweet and update the users status without the user logging in right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need both and can store both in MYSQL database for use.
You need to get them to authenticate